# Viewing xampp wordpress sites over lan

Tags: linux, wordpress, xampp

Im trying to setup Wordpress dev environment.
We are setting up a Wordpress dev server (linuxmint 11) and users need to see the sites on clients pc and possibly over the internet too. 
I have installed Xammp and have setup our wp site. I am able to load it in the localhosts' browser as localhost/mysite
But when I try on a client pc over the lan, using the servers ip (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/mysite) only the text loads and the pictures fail to load. I can access the the phpmyadmin using the ip of the server in the browser.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That´s why path´s to images use localhost/bla bla... on the ddbb, and once you are trying to whatch it by IP, well, can´t do it.

Take a look on code and you will see what i mean.

Hope it helps.